# While loop not working with fgetc

Tags: c, string, while-loop, fifo, fgetc

So here's what is am trying to do:

1. I am asking the user to input a number of sentences
2. Whenever he wants to stop he will press Q (captial letter)
3. And then the next processing should start.

What i am getting right now:

1. The user is prompted to enter as many sentences as he wants
2. But when he presses Q the control doesn't shift from the while loop to the next instruction.

It is a FIFO program.If you see any other errors do report them.Thanks!

Here's the Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
void main()
{

int i=0,fd;
char str[500]="",ch;

char *myfifo="/home/rahulp/Desktop/myfifo";

mkfifo(myfifo,0666);    

printf("Enter the sentences:");

while((ch=fgetc(stdin))!='Q')
{
    printf("ch===%c",ch);
    str[i++]=ch;

}
str[i]='\0';

fd=open(myfifo,O_WRONLY);

if(fd<0)
{
    printf("Cannot open fifo");
}
else
{
    write(fd,str,strlen(str));
}

close(fd);
unlink(myfifo); 
}
```

Comment: just to make sure, you are pressing shift+q to try to quit right?

Comment: Note that fgetc() returns `int`, not `char`. Also, this shouldn't even compile, `printf("ch===%c"ch);` is missing a comma. Please be more diligent when posting code.

Comment: @Jacobr365 yep i a \m using shift+q.

Comment: After making it compile (by including `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, `fcntl.h` and `string.h` and adding the comma) it does exit the loop after entering `Q` (and enter). It is hanging on the `open`, waiting for some other process to open the fifo for reading.

Comment: @Jens yeah. Sorry about that. Correct me if i am wrong, if `fgetc` returns `int` then how do i get a character in the `ch` variable? I am still learning C. So sorry for noobish questions.

Comment: @RahulPadalkar You don't. You declare `ch` as an `int` and when you fgetc() something you *must* test the result for `EOF` or you will run into a non-terminating loop if the user types the end-of-file character.

Comment: @Kenney If i put `printf("Out of while loop");` above `open` call, i don't get the printf statement in my terminal.Is it supposed to run or not?

Comment: I did the same thing, and it did print.. Remember you have to press 3 keys: `shift`+`Q` followed by the `enter` key, since the input is line-buffered..

Comment: @Jens I don't get it.I have declared ch as a char varaible not an int. When i run the program it actually prints the value of ch as a char.Can you post please post corrected code?

Comment: @Kenney i tried using Caps.Didn't work!

Comment: Maybe "it works", but both `fgetc` and `'Q'` have the `int` type. Remember that `printf` promotes a `char` type to `int`, so that's no proof that `char` is correct.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns value in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF`, a negative number.  This is typically 256 + 1 different values.  Saving that result in a `char ch` (typically 256 different values) loses distinctiveness.  Save `fgets()` rersults as an `int`, test if `EOF`. It not, then treating it as a character value  is OK.

Comment: @Rahul: you're still missing the `,` after the `"ch===%c"` in your snippet. I tested it on Linux and it works fine: `gcc fifo.c; /bin/echo -e "Foo\nQ\n" | ./a.out`, and in another terminal `cat myfifo`.

Comment: @Kenney  It works now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jens Thanks! It works now!

Comment: @RahulPadalkar Great! The next step on Stackoverflow is to upvote and accept the answer that was most helpful.

Comment: @Jens Already did that!

Comment: Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible, even with variable width fonts.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability and documentation, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code has a logic problem.  Specifically, if the file fails to open, then do not call `close()` on that file descriptor.  Doing so can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: rather than this line: `printf("Cannot open fifo");`, it is much better to include that system message about the error AND to output the message to stderr rather than stdout.  Suggest: `perror( "open for fifo failed" );` followed by: `unlink(myfifo);` and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the possibility that something with mkfifo is going on, this is how you should read stdin:

```
int ch;

printf("Enter the sentences:");
fflush(stdout);

while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
{
    if (ch == 'Q')
        break;
    printf("ch=%c\n", ch);
    str[i++]=ch;
}
str[i]='\0';
```